# How to add the values of a key in an array of objects?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add all the values of 'fte' key and give it as a single value to 'fte'.

```
  myArray = [{ account: "Netflix",
          fte: [1,2,1]
        },
        { account: "Ace",
          fte: [1,1]
        },
        { account: "Absa",
          fte: [2,1,3,0.5]
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure if I get you. The code below adds all fte values to one array. But maybe you wanted to sum all those values? R3Tep´s solution adds all arrays to an array.

```js
"use strict";
var ftes = new Array();
var arr = [{ account: "Netflix",
                    fte: [1, 2, 1]
                },
                { account: "Ace",
                    fte: [1, 1]
                },
                { account: "Absa",
                    fte: [2, 1, 3, 0.5]
                }
            ];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ftes = ftes.concat(arr[i].fte);
}

// All accounts fte values is now added to ftes
console.log(ftes)
```